# SQL group by query not working error ORA-00979

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to add up the different crimes in each area so i can see the total number of each crime for each area. the query below is what i have tried.

```
SELECT  Area_Offence_id, Offence_Name , SUM (No_Of_Offences)
FROM    Area_Offence
GROUP   BY Area_Offence_id;
```

Comment: you have to add Offence_Name field also in group by clause

Answer (score 1):

You select Offence_Name which is not used in GROUP BY. You should use an aggregate function when selecting this field.

For example the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT Area_Offence_id, MIN(Offence_Name) , SUM (No_Of_Offences) 
FROM Area_Offence 
GROUP BY Area_Offence_id;
```

You can also use Offence_Name in group by clause instead. 
For example:

```
SELECT Area_Offence_id, Offence_Name , SUM (No_Of_Offences) 
FROM Area_Offence 
GROUP BY Area_Offence_id, Offence_Name;
```

**Rule of thumb**: Always check what fields you select when using Group By clause. Group by  collects data across multiple records and group the results by the columns you specify. If you don't specify the column in group by, then you should use a aggregate function (like sum, count, min, max) if you want to select it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Area_Offence_id, Offence_Name, SUM(No_Of_Offences) 
FROM Area_Offence 
GROUP BY Area_Offence_id,Offence_Name;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add all not calculated columns in group by clause.